# Weird error with CommonJs under Webpack4 + babel8 + coreJs@3

Tags: webpack, babeljs, commonjs

This is the entrance:

```
// index.js
const {test} = require('./handle')
test()
```

This is a commonjs module

```
// handle.js
module.exports = {
  test() {
    console.log('>>>>>   handle get trigger')
    console.log(typeof [])
  }
}
```

Compile success,then I got this error while running

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
```

If I remove `console.log(typeof [])` from `handle.js`, the error disappear.

my babel config is:

```
{
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                        plugins: [
                            [
                                "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                                {
                                    "corejs": 3
                                }
                            ],
                            "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                include: /src/
            },
```

The error also disapper when I use ES6 module to write this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` adds `import` to my files!
So it become a mix use of ES6Module and CommonJs !
 That cause the problem!!!!!!

So,we can only use Es6module or add a babel plugin `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`